# Angular with Angular Material - service call on MatTab focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got a child `@Component` which contains a `MatTabGroup` with a couple of `MatTab`(s).

I'd like to load the `MatTab`(s)' content (which is dependent on a service call) only at focus time.

I've looked at the `API`s, maybe the `selectedTabChange` event is the right way? What if the `MatTab` is the first one (which means it is displayed immediatly)? Any other advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectedTabChanged is the only way, Tabs generally work in such a way you need to click on them inorder to get it activated.

So selectedTabChanged  fires once you select the tab.The selectedTabChanged event has to be attached to the **`<mat-tab-group>`**

if you want the service to be called on the first tab, call it when the component is initiated via ngOninit().

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2pgt1-3uip3a?file=app%2Ftabs-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

To load the content of MatTabs only when they are in focus, you can use Angular's *ngIf directive along with the selectedTabChange event of MatTabGroup. This way, you can conditionally render the content of a tab when it becomes selected.

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
      <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 3">Tab 3 Content</mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
    <your-component [selectedTabIndex]="selectedTabIndex"></your-component>
```

and in ts

```
 selectedTabIndex = 0;

  onTabChanged(event: any): void {
    this.selectedTabIndex = event.index;
  }
```

and then in your other component

is html part

```
<div *ngIf="selectedTabIndex === 0">Content for Tab 1</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedTabIndex === 1">Content for Tab 2</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedTabIndex === 2">Content for Tab 3</div>
```

and in ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Input() selectedTabIndex: number = 0
```